# Is it possible to get the number of pixels of the detected object with Detectron2?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, detectron

I'm totally new to deep learning. I have a Detectron2 model detecting solar panels located on rooftops. I'd love to calculate the surface of the detected panels, therefore I need to get the number of pixels of detected objects. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use  [official framework](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2) and segmentation over detections (for more precise surface estimation) on image `im` like:

```
outputs = predictor(im)
```

Dict `outputs` has the key `instances`  (you can see [source code](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2/blob/42c44b622eb7b179576bdac218c84c107fff8eab/detectron2/utils/visualizer.py#L401)) - you can just take the masks boolean tensors and calculate its sum:

```
masks = outputs['instances'].pred_masks
masks.shape

# torch.Size([15, 480, 640])
```

So we have here 15 objects and boolean masks size of input image as masks for each object, now we calculate total amount of pixels for each detected object:

```
torch.sum(torch.flatten(masks, start_dim=1),dim=1)

# tensor([32251,  8786,  2513, 11821,  1395,  2129,   496,  2722,  1020,   571,
     1060,   806,  2006,   535,   297], device='cuda:0')
```